# text highlighting using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlighting

I am trying to use a text highlight option using javascript.I know how to find the start postiion of the string, bt how do I make it highlight. my code looks like

```
<div id="entity">health insurance</div>
<div id="article">This kind of insurance is meant to supplement health insurance for cancer-care costs. But generally you're better off putting your money toward comprehensive health policies. </div>
```

and the javascript that I have used it

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var test=document.getElementById('article').innerHTML;
var variable=document.getElementById('entity').innerHTML;
alert(test.search(new RegExp(variable, "i")));
});
```

This will alert the start postion of the string.

Comment: Clarify your question.What do you want to highlight, is it the div containing text?

Comment: The content inside entity id should be highlighted inside article id..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="entity">health insurance</div>
<div id="article">This kind of insurance is meant to supplement health insurance for cancer-care costs. But generally you're better off putting your money toward comprehensive health policies. </div>​
```

CSS:

```
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {​
  var $test = $('#article');
  var entityText = $('#entity').html();
  var highlight = '<span class="highlight">' + entityText + '</span>';
  $test.html($test.html().replace(entityText, highlight));
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ehzPQ/2/

So, I'm just replacing the first occurrence of the 'entity' string with the same string wrapped up in a span class.

Did I understood your problem right?

**-----------------------UPDATE-------------------------**

If you want to highlight all the occurrences modify use a regular expression:

Updated Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $test = $('#article');
  var entityText = $('#entity').html();
  var entityRegularExpression = new RegExp("\\b" + entityText + "\\b", "gi");
  var highlight = '<span class="highlight">' + entityText + '</span>';
  $test.html($test.html().replace(entityRegularExpression, highlight))
}
```

And updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ehzPQ/3/

Comment: Could you tell me what this statement does  ' var entityRegularExpression = new RegExp(entityText,"g")' ?

Comment: It creates a regular expression using the content of 'entityText', the 'g' stands for global. So, if 'entityText = "foo"' the regular expression will look for all the occurrences of 'foo' in a string. i.e. its equivalent to '/foo/g'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009219/ignoring-fuzzy-match-and-add-exact-wrd-pattern-matching-using-javascript

Comment: do u know what to do if a . or $ symbol comes in between the matching wrds... using this form, the $ or dot symbol wont get highlighted..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015699/pattern-matchin-using-javascript-doesnt-wrk-when-special-characters-and-numbers#comment14398845_11015699

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `yourDesireString` with something like `<span class='highlight'>yourDesireString</span>`.

```
span.highlight {
     background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: it will nt be fixed one...Ive just given a static example..what if the content im going to highlight is generated realtime

Comment: So do the replace job dynamically.