# ignoring fuzzy match and add exact word pattern matching using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a text highlight option for my website. But I want exact word match instead of fuzzy word match, The code that I have matches all kind of instances and it has some case sensitivity issues. If we take the Jfiddle example, I only want to add the word **cancer**, case sensitivity should nt be an issue. and ignore fuzzy matches, like cancerous and bycanceraous(I know there is not a word like that, but could not think of any for the example). I have the jfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/ehzPQ/6/

HTML:

```
<div id="entity">cancer</div>
<div id="article">
  This kind of insurance is meant to supplement health insurance for cancerous-care costs. But generally you're better off putting your money toward comprehensive health policies. The I just repeat health insurance, because it sounds so good! health insurance, health insurance, I can never grow tired of it... Cancer is seriously a dangerouse disease. Test case : bycanceraous
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.highlight {
    background-color: yellow
}​
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $test = $('#article');
  var entityText = $('#entity').html();
  var entityRegularExpression = new RegExp(entityText,"g");
  var highlight = '<span class="highlight">' + entityText + '</span>';
  $test.html($test.html().replace(entityRegularExpression, highlight));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to utilize Regular Expression's [Word Boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Change the following line:

```
var entityRegularExpression = new RegExp(entityText, "g");
```

To this:

```
var entityRegularExpression = new RegExp("\\b" + entityText + "\\b", "gi");
```

[Here's the updated jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ehzPQ/14/)
*Note: I updated the article text to contain some instances of the word so you could see it work.*

You can also take it a step further and have the case insensitive matches retain their original case, by utilizing Regular Expression's [Callbacks](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1742-Using-Regular-Expressions-In-Javascript-A-General-Overview-.htm). Check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehzPQ/10/) for the code and example.

Comment: He wants it to be case-insensitive. You should add an `i` next to the `g`: `new RegExp("\\b" + entityText + "\\b", "gi")`.

Comment: @benekastah Good call. I couldn't tell if he meant he wants it case insensitive or not.

Comment: since we are replacing the found wrd pattern. once the uppercase match is found, it replaces with the lower case.. you could se that in our example..

Comment: @user1371896 Yep, just updated the answer with that. [Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehzPQ/10/) for that.

Comment: Please check the jsfiddle, its nt wrking properly.. Its replacing it as CaNCEr

Comment: @user1371896 I'm not sure what you mean. I typed one of them in the article as CaNCEr to show that it will replace the word highlighted exactly as it is capitalized in the original article.

Comment: @user1371896 No need to apologize, no worries :) Guess I should have used a less crazy example. Glad it helped you out.

Comment: There's no need to use callbacks for replacing, just use `$&`, `$1` etc.

Comment: What if symbols like $ or . come in between

Comment: @thg435 is correct, a callback is not needed. You can test with [this updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehzPQ/14/).

Comment: @NatePinchot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015699/pattern-matchin-using-javascript-doesnt-wrk-when-special-characters-and-numbers