# pattern matchin using javascript doesnt wrk when special characters and numbers come in between

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a pattern matching to find word contents in an article for my website.. I am unable to make the pattern matchings when a special character or a number comes in between the words, I will add the jsfiddle link.. also is it possible to find the number of occurences and add a button which on clicking go to each occurence one by one...This is the way my pgrm is currently wrking http://jsfiddle.net/ehzPQ/12/

Comment: Can you give an example of text that doesn't match?

Comment: When I try to look for e.g. `see 2008`, the proper part gets highlighted. The some goes for `it's`. Your example seems to work (though I didn'T spot any special characters...)

Comment: a text like 'test9?test'

Comment: Are you saying you want to treat "special characters" and numbers as breaks between words? (Please define "special" - I don't consider a question mark very special.)

Comment: `?` has special meaning in [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions). So you need to do something with these characters.

Comment: check out this example http://jsfiddle.net/ehzPQ/12/

Comment: and $ I hope u consider dollar as spcl one... :)

Comment: If you construct a regex from a string you need to escape any characters that have special meaning in a regex, including the `.` on the end of your `cancer9.` example. (And no, I don't consider `$` to be very special - I don't consider any character that appears on a standard keyboard particularly special unless the context in which they're "special" is clearly indicated.)

Comment: so the highlighting wont wrk if a $ sign or a dot symbol comes in between the words that I am trying to match?

Comment: I wanna highlight these symbols as well if it is coming in between the terms that I am trying to highlight.

Comment: I think that you need to define what are the boundaries you want for your searches, I think you can't add all special characters in the search and don't have fuzzy match. I'll post an answer with that in mind soon.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem has to do with the boundaries you choose for your words, I believe that with \b you are not taking into account the case where the word is has a dot before (like ".cancer9". But I'm really not an expert in regex... so, I worked a little bit and got this solution, but I'm not sure if it will work for you:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $test = $('#article');
  var entityText = $('#entity').html().replace(/\./g, "\\\.").replace(/\$/g, "\\\$").replace(/\?/g, "\\\?"); //etc...
  var entityRegularExpression =new RegExp("([^a-zA-Z0-9])(" + entityText + ")([^a-zA-Z0-9])", "gi");
  var highlight = '$1<span class="highlight">$2</span>$3';
  $test.html($test.html().replace(entityRegularExpression, highlight));
});
```

And here you have a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ehzPQ/20/

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks it wrkd..bt should nt there be an easier way to resolve this puntuation or symbol issue..instead of adding all the possible ones by ourselves...

Comment: I didn't test it, but `stringToReplace.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '\\\$&')` may work.